# I don't know how to fix the eyes

Tags: modeling

I don't know how to fix the eyes.

[image]
 Ctrl+r is not useful and when I try to move the edges Blender doesn't accept it.

Here the edges are fine put when I reder the picture is different.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you upload your file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You are using mostly triangles. There is no way to use loop cuts(Ctrl+R) with triangles.

Comment: Yes, I am going to do it right now.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upload...can you tell me how please?

Comment: you need to open this link:  blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, drag your file in and copy the address of this question into the field

Comment: The problem is that you are most likely using **Subdivision Surface** modifier which doesn't work well with triangles, so either turn off the **Subsurf** modifier or convert your model to quads.